# SQL how to count each value in multiple columns and same rows?

Tags: sql

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | A |
| C | D | C |

for example lets say I have a dataset like this. I want to count the values, each value in multiple columns and same rows. As a result it has to say the count of the values I put into.

```
2A 1B and 
2C 1D
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: SQL Server <> Oracle - please correct your tags.

Comment: I've no idea what you really want to do – can you provide a more precise example including data samples and desired output?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I edited the question, can you look at it again? I want to count the values in one row.

Comment: UNPIVOT and then GROUP the results. Later CONCATENATE the COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

You don't count values in a row, you count values in a column. So, you use sql to reformat your data in to a single column, then count the values in the usual way.

```sql
SELECT
  column_value,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT col1 AS column_value FROM your_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col2 AS column_value FROM your_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col3 AS column_value FROM your_table
)
  AS pivoted
GROUP BY
  column_value
ORDER BY
  column_value
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, here is the code for the same. Can be optimized a bit by removing multiple select statements.

```
Declare @val Varchar(MAX); 
Select @val=COALESCE(@val + ' ' + result, result) 
FROM (
SELECT CONCAT(cnt,col) result FROM (
SELECT col, count(*)cnt FROM (
SELECT col
FROM
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 
  from #temp
) AS cp
UNPIVOT 
(
  col FOR cols IN (col1, col2, col3 )
) AS up)t
group by col)t)t2

select @val
```

---